# nodejs do something after multiple functions complete

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm having a problem that I can't seem to get around.

Imaging the following

```
if (users) {
 for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  apiData.users = getUserDetails(users[i]);
 }
}
```

and

```
if(profiles) {
 for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
  apiData.profiles = getProfileDetails(users[i]);
 }
}
```

now, only once both of those blocks of code have been completed (i.e. the API calls have returned the results that are required), would I like to do something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
 saveUserProfile(apiData)
}
```

Normally I handle a situation like this by wrapping the first block of code in a function that returns a callback and then running the third function afterwards, but how can I do this when there are effectively 2 separate operations happening?

To be clear, I would like to avoid saving users and profiles separately, there are various reasons for this.

I would like to know if there is any standard way of handling a situation like this as there may or may not be users or profiles, so using callbacks seems like it will not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) module to achieve this.
Use `async.parallel()` function since your first and second snippets do not depend on each other, and can run asynchronously, but you wish to make third snippet run when first and second are done executing.

Assuming `users`, `profiles`, and `apiData` are already declared, **your code would look like**

```
function func1(callback){
  if (users) {
   for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    apiData.users = getUserDetails(users[i]);
   }
  }
  //invoke callback 
}

function func2(callback){
  if(profiles) {
   for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
    apiData.profiles = getProfileDetails(users[i]);
   }
  }
  //invoke callback
}

var asyncfunc = [];
asyncfunc.push(func1);
asyncfunc.push(func2);

async.parallel(asyncfunc,function(err,result){
  //result is an array which receives the second argument of each function's callback.
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    saveUserProfile(apiData)
  }
})
```

**EDIT**
PS: you can also use [async.series()](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) here. Both are equivalent in this case, since the functions handled by `async.parallel()` here do not use timers neither perform I/O tasks.

The `callback` in each function inside the array takes two arguments. First argument represents error, which is `null` if there are no errors, second represents the result of the function, which is passed to the  second argument of the `async.parallel()` function's callback.

Comment: thanks! I've never used async before but it seems you need to always return a callback with the functions in async.

Comment: pardon me. I edited the answer accordingly. thanxx for pointing out :)